# HTML required character set for form fields

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have created an online forum with a username and password field.  The problem is that I would like to add restrictions on the input to weed out invalid username formats. (Valid username will start with the first 3 characters as XYZ). Is there anyway I can set up a rule that if the first 3 letters of username STARTS with let's say ABC, the Submit button will grey out and display a message that that username is not valid before it checks with the server?  But if the user types the required beginning format letters correctly then the Submit button will be enabled?

I tried making the code using the same principals as the @ sign being required in an email address but have had strange results.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. However you need to post the code you've tried, showing where you got stuck, in your question.

Comment: Agreed, there's a million ways to do this, let's see the code you've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the HTML5 [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern):

```html
<style>
:invalid { border-color: red }
</style>
<form>
<label for=uname>Username:</label>
<input id=uname name=uname type=text pattern="XYZ.*">
<p><input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

The example uses CSS to indicate an invalid field with red border, for illustration.

The code accepts literally any string that starts with XYZ (case-sensitively), including the string XYZ. Modify as needed.

Since the `pattern` attribute is not universally supported, you probably want to add JavaScript code that performs a similar check. In it, using a regular expression, as in a `pattern` attribute, is the simplest approach.

Comment: you are the best!  I thought of using that pattern attribute but when i read it on w3 it kind of confused me but thanks for clearing it up for me!